# Python: How do you open a separate output file?

Tags: python, output, alphabetical

The following code lists the occurrence of each word in a text file. Now I wanna open a similar output file, but in alphabetical order in a separate output file. What would be my first step?

```
print("What's the name of the file?")
    file_name = input()
    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    wordcount={}
    for word in file.read().split():
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
    for a,b in wordcount.items():
        print(a, b)
```

Comment: @MM My apologies, Python is the language.

Comment: Can you make the question a little more clear? What specifically are you trying to to with alphabetical order

Comment: Have you done any research at all on how to write to files?

Comment: @Natecat I am basically trying to do the same thing as what the code given already does. Except 1)Make the words alphabetical and 2) Open it in a separate output file.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean input file? output file would be a file you are writing too

Comment: As was said before there is no output file so far. So `separate output file` confuses. So far you are opening a text file and making a dictionary, that counts instances of all words. Then you print that dictionary. (apart from indentation issues). Do also want to print an alphabetic list of the dictionary? Then turn it into a list, and sort the list.

Comment: @mets17: That's ok.  I'm not a Python person so I needed to know if I could answer or not. :-)

Comment: If someones answer helped you, please click the checkmark under the voting arrows for their question to accept their answer

Answer (score 1):

Your first step would be to sort the words in alphabetical order obviously. In order to do this, you can utilize pythons built in sorting methods. First, get the list of keys in your dictionary, which is your word list, using `words=wordcount.keys()` and then you can sort that wordlist alphabetically by using something like `words.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
txt='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
wordcount={}
for word in txt.split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

list1=[]        
for a,b in wordcount.items():
    # print(a, b)
    list1.append([  a.lower(),b])

print sorted(list1, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Output:

```
[['ad', 1], ['adipiscing', 1], ['aliqua.', 1], ['aliquip', 1], ['amet,', 1], ['anim', 1], ['aute', 1], ['cillum', 1], ['commodo', 1], ['consectetur', 1], ['consequat.', 1], ['culpa', 1], ['cupidatat', 1], ['deserunt', 1], ['do', 1], ['dolor', 2], ['dolore', 2], ['duis', 1], ['ea', 1], ['eiusmod', 1], ['elit,', 1], ['enim', 1], ['esse', 1], ['est', 1], ['et', 1], ['eu', 1], ['ex', 1], ['excepteur', 1], ['exercitation', 1], ['fugiat', 1], ['id', 1], ['in', 3], ['incididunt', 1], ['ipsum', 1], ['irure', 1], ['labore', 1], ['laboris', 1], ['laborum.', 1], ['lorem', 1], ['magna', 1], ['minim', 1], ['mollit', 1], ['nisi', 1], ['non', 1], ['nostrud', 1], ['nulla', 1], ['occaecat', 1], ['officia', 1], ['pariatur.', 1], ['proident,', 1], ['qui', 1], ['quis', 1], ['reprehenderit', 1], ['sed', 1], ['sint', 1], ['sit', 1], ['sunt', 1], ['tempor', 1], ['ullamco', 1], ['ut', 1], ['ut', 2], ['velit', 1], ['veniam,', 1], ['voluptate', 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to use `collections` and doing something like this to sort the dictionary based on the keys.

```
import collections
wordcount = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(wordcount.items()))
```

Then you could just loop through each one a write it to the file.

```
outPath = "PathToOutFile"

outFile = open(outPath,"w");
for a,b in wordcount.items():
     outFile.write("{:s} {:d}\n".format(a,b))
```